# Retaining property in arc

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, automatic-ref-counting, retain

I am new at objective-c.I have a question .I know little about Retain .All i know is Retaining an object creates a strong reference, and an object cannot be deallocated until all of its strong references are released. If two objects retain each other, neither object ever gets deallocated because the connection between them cannot be broken. In ARC we can not retain a object. But we can retain a property.
What is the difference between retaining a object and retaining a property.

Thank You 
Happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

After searching so many articles and links, I decided to put all the attributes information together:

1. atomic //default
2. nonatomic
3. strong=retain //default
4. weak
5. retain
6. assign //default
7. unsafe_unretained
8. copy
9. readonly
10. readwrite //default

    Many thanks to all the people who give best answers here!!

Comment: Could you explain these words in more detail? Or just share a link to the explanation of them.

Comment: @Miroslav yah sure can you get the detail here                              http://rdcworld-iphone.blogspot.in/2012/12/variable-property-attributes-or.html

Answer (score 0):

a property is retain, mean the class own the property NSObject, that's nothing about ARC. ARC just do auto release reference count.

Comment: But it increase the reference count of the object to +1.I think it is related to Arc.